# Comparing text of two fields in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, string-comparison

I'm trying to judge by the name of a car dealership whether a specific car is their brand or not. So with:

```
select car_make, dealer_name, 
case when ('%' || dealer_name || '%') ilike car_make THEN 'OnBrand'
END
from table
```

Ideally, when searching a car with make Nissan and a dealer named Local Nissan Dealer, the third column would contain OnBrand, but it's returning

```
Nissan    Local Nissan Dealer    <null>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got your wildcards backwards, you want:

```
case when dealer_name ilike ('%' || car_make || '%') THEN 'OnBrand'
```

Comment: This also returns a null for that field.

Comment: Well the syntax is correct this way, but it's not in the question.  Can you provide a complete example row and the table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement).

Comment: Is it not possible to do this syntax in 8.1? That's the only thing I can think of that might drop your example from working. Both fields are VARCHAR and not null.

Comment: I will look.  Can you provide the full table definition/schema please?  That would be the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  -- The case statement has been available since at least Pg 7.4  If you are not getting an actual error when issuing the query, then it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address why your particular statement isn't working (@user's solution looks good to me), but as an alternative, potentially simpler syntax, what about a regular expression?

```
select
  car_make, dealer_name, 
  case when dealer_name ~ car_make THEN 'OnBrand' end
from table
```